# Why is the Network Link Conditioner preference pane crashing as soon as I turn it on?

Tags: crash, macos, xcode

I am trying to use the [Network Link Conditioner](http://mattgemmell.com/2011/07/25/network-link-conditioner-in-lion/) preference pane included with the Hardware IO tools in the developer tools to throttle Internet speeds. I can open and load the preference pane, but as soon as I try to turn it on, System Preferences crashes.
[image]
Why is this happening and how can I fix it? I have a 13" MacBook Pro with a 2.3 GHz Intel Core i5 running OS 10.7.3.
Here's the log entry for the NLC crash:

```
5/10/12 9:31:39.150 AM [0x0-0x1c51c5].com.apple.systempreferences: NLCd : Bootstrap failure
```

Comment: I have exactly the same symptoms as you :(

Comment: Could be lots of reasons.  Did you use `Console` to check the logs?  Meanwhile, since Network Link Conditioner is just a front end for `ipfw` you can [use ipfw directly](http://titaniumninja.com/simulating-slow-network-links-on-os-x/).

Comment: @OldPro I've updated my question to include the Console log information.

Comment: You've downloaded the latest Xcode from the MAS?

Comment: @da4 Yes I have.

Comment: Have you tried Getting Info on System Preferences and setting it to open in 32-bit mode, then trying to access this prefpane?

Comment: @da4 It still crashes.

Comment: Any update on this I too am having the same problem?

Comment: @odyth No update...I'm still having the problem too...

Comment: I just solved it see my response below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I filed a bug report (#11891721) for this. I linked to [odyth's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/51551/7833) in the report and this is their response.

> Changing the nlcd file over to an older version makes it compatible
>   with the preference pane, (as you did in this case). The current
>   version of the prefpane works with the latest nlcd.  We can not do
>   anything about the older installs of nlcd or the prefpane that you
>   have.
>
> We are closing this bug since we are aware of the issue.
>
> Please be sure to regularly check the seed notes and release notes for
>   any updates that might affect this issue.  Again, thank you for taking
>   the time to submit bugs.  We sincerely appreciate your input.

So there's the official answer.

Comment: In other words, i was having the same problem on OS X Lion using the Hardware IO Tools from February 2012. After reading this answer i tried the Hardware IO Tools from Late July 2012 (which is announced for OS X Mountain Lion) and it worked fine.

Answer (score 7):

Just a quick note to say that I eventually stopped the crashing by manually copying these two files from another OS X machine and then manually starting the nlcd daemon
(if you don't have another Mac, I posted my copies of those files [here](http://www.4shared.com/zip/asfw6ACz/networkLinkConditionerFiles.html))

Copied these files:
`/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.NetworkLinkConditioner.plist`
`/usr/libexec/nlcd`
Run these three commands:

```
sudo chown root /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.NetworkLinkConditioner.plist      
sudo chmod 644 /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.NetworkLinkConditioner.plist   
sudo launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.NetworkLinkConditioner.plist
```

After that the pref pane didn't unexpectedly exit when moving the switch to 'on'.

Taken from https://devforums.apple.com/message/645980#645980

Comment: So sorry I didn't see this!! I did try this and it seems to work. However, I need to try it out on a faster network. Give me a few days to test it out. Thanks!

Comment: Seems to work and the bandwidth is being limited, so I accepted your answer. Thanks so much! Now I just wish Apple would get their act together and fix this. Off to submit some Apple feedback!

Comment: Is it possible to share those files on a different server? It seems like we have to signup and the language cannot be set to english...

Comment: Can you please upload it on another place? I can't download it anymore ...

Comment: Indeed... that website malware heaven.

Comment: The files I uploaded still work just fine, but I uploaded it to my dropbox https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7698018/networkLinkConditionerFiles.zip.

Comment: Also as of iOS 6 Network Link Conditioner is built into the phone itself, which I have found to be more useful then using the version on my computer.  Settings > Developer > Network Link Conditioner.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in Yosemite.

Tried with the files mentioned here, but it was still crashing.

Giving admin rights to my OS X user seemed to "solve" the issue.
In other words, **running the app as a "Standard" user seems to cause the crash** for me.

Still it is not a nice solution, but maybe it helps some people or give insight for a better solution. :)

Comment: this is still true for macOS Sierra 10.12.3