# Is there any way to run Network Link Condition from a Standard User account?

Tags: network, security, permission, user-account

There is a known issue in Network Link Conditioner where if you install it in the normal way (Xcode > Open Developer Tool > More Developer Tools > Install Hardware Tools) it will run from an Admin account but crash in a Standard account.

For increased security, I develop from a Standard account. Is there any way to run Network Link Condition from my standard account without switching to the Admin account?

Related questions:

- [Why is the Network Link Conditioner preference pane crashing as soon as I turn it on?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/49241/why-is-the-network-link-conditioner-preference-pane-crashing-as-soon-as-i-turn-i)
- [Network Link Conditioner not working](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/79400/network-link-conditioner-not-working)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start the System Preferences.app as Admin and from that use the Network Link Conditioner.prefpane.

To do so use the following shell command:

```
sudo /Applications/System\ Preferences.app/Contents/MacOS/System\ Preferences
```

or the following AppleScript command:

```
do shell script "/Applications/System\ Preferences.app/Contents/MacOS/System\ Preferences" with administrator privileges
```

When I click on the Network Link Conditioner in the window that is opened after the password is given, I get a message that System Preferences needs to be restartet to open the PrefPane. After agreeing to this the Network Link Conditioner is working for me while I'm logged in as normal (non-admin) user in 10.10.

In macOS Big Sur, the command is

```
sudo /System/Applications/System\ Preferences.app/Contents/MacOS/System\ Preferences
```

In macOS Ventura, the command is

```
sudo /System/Applications/System\ Settings.app/Contents/MacOS/System\ Settings
```